# Executable "C:\Windows\System32\Fodhelper.exe" not found

Tags: c++, redirect, wow64

I am trying to start the above builtin Windows executable from within a C++ program. Firstly I can confirm that the program does exist, at the path "C:\Windows\System32\fodhelper.exe"

[image: System32 Directory]

I have tried 3 different methods for running this program:

- `System()`
- `ShellExecuteW()`
- `CreateProcessW()`

None of these methods work. The error I receive is: `The system cannot find the file specified.`

Due to the fact that I can start this executable as my usual Windows account from the start menu, run box and from within Windows explorer, i believe that my user account does have the privileges to run the program. Also, I am not receiving an access denied error from my code. Regardless, I have run VS as an Administrator and I have still experienced the same problem.

I believe the code I am using to start the process is correct, as the same code will start `cmd.exe` without issue. See below:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>

void CreateProcessMethod(LPCWSTR programPath) {

    HRESULT result;
    STARTUPINFO startupInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation;

    ZeroMemory(&startupInfo, sizeof(startupInfo));
    startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);
    ZeroMemory(&processInformation, sizeof(processInformation));

    result = CreateProcessW(programPath, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &startupInfo, &processInformation);
    if (result == 0) {

        wchar_t buf[256];
        FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
            NULL, GetLastError(), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
            buf, (sizeof(buf) / sizeof(wchar_t)), NULL);

        /* Display error */
        std::wcout << programPath << " not started: " << buf << std::endl;

    }
    else {
        std::wcout << programPath << " started successfuly" << std::endl;
    }

}

void ShellExecuteMethod(LPCWSTR programPath) {

    SHELLEXECUTEINFOW shExecInfo = { 0 };
    shExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFOW);

        
    shExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI;
    shExecInfo.hwnd = nullptr;
    shExecInfo.lpVerb = L"open";
    shExecInfo.lpFile = programPath;
    shExecInfo.lpParameters = L"\\C";
    shExecInfo.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;

    if (ShellExecuteExW(&shExecInfo) == 0)
    {
        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_CANCELLED) // Operation canceled by the user
        {
            wchar_t buf[256];
            FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
                NULL, GetLastError(), MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
                buf, (sizeof(buf) / sizeof(wchar_t)), NULL);

            /* Display error */
            std::wcout << programPath << " not started: " << buf << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else {
        std::wcout << programPath << " started successfuly" << std::endl;
    }

}

int main(){

    CreateProcessMethod(L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe");
    CreateProcessMethod(L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\fodhelper.exe");

    ShellExecuteMethod(L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe");
    ShellExecuteMethod(L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\fodhelper.exe");

    
}
```

See output of the program below:

[image: Output window]

Does anyone have any insight into what exactly I am doing wrong here? I cannot find any information that relates to this issue. Is far as I can understand, the code attempting to run the program is correct, works with different executables. This also occurs with three different methods. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: Are you compiling in 32-bit mode on 64-bit Windows, by any chance?

Comment: I MAY be, could you please explain how this would cause this error? I'll look into that also, it hasn't caused me any problems up to press if that is the issue, as such I'm quite interested as to why that is a problem.

Comment: phuclv explained it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

32-bit applications running on WOW64 will be put under [file system redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector). Therefore if your app is a 32-bit one, the path `C:\Windows\System32\fodhelper.exe` will be redirected to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\fodhelper.exe` which doesn't exist. You have some solutions:

- Use `SysNative` to access the real system32 folder, which means you need to use something like `system(R"(C:\Windows\SysNative\fodhelper.exe)");`
- Turn off file system redirection explicitly (should be avoided in general)
- Or better compiling your exe as a 64-bit app.

Comment: Perfect. That solution works for me. A rookie mistake! Great explanation also, with an explanatory link.

Comment: Nothing wrong with disabling the FS redirector temporarily. The main problem with using `SysNative` *properly* is you should not be hard-coding `C:\Windows`, you should be asking Windows where it is actually installed, via `GetWindowsDirectory()`, `SHGetFolderPath(CSIDL_WINDOWS)`, or `SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Windows)`, and then append `SysNative\fodhelper.exe` to that path. Or use `ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%windir%\SysNative\fodhelper.exe")`. Not everyone installs in `C:\Windows`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau true. File system redirection exists exactly because programmers hard coded paths like windows, system32...

Comment: I compiled as an x64 executable and that resolved my issues, however I can appreciate for code stability it would be better to request the `%windir%`  from the Win32api instead of assuming where it resides